# Using class member function as Callback

Tags: c++, callback

In PortAudio's C++ bindings, there is a MemFunCallBackStream constructior that can be called as:

```
portaudio::MemFunCallbackStream<MyClass> streamRecord(paramsRecord, 
                                                     *AnInstanceOfMyClass,
                                                     &MyClass::MemberFunction);
```

where last parameter is the callback function. However without using the & operator on that parameter compiler fails. But as far as I know & parameter is omitable when obtaining address of functions to use in function pointers. Is this somehow different from C callback function and ptr. to func. syntax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html#faq-33.2) seems to suggest that you **can** omit the `&` (for static member functions, at least), but then goes on to give various reasons why you shouldn't confuse ordinary function-pointers with C++ member-function-pointers.

**EDIT**: Found more information [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/FastDelegate.aspx), which is relevant to non-static member functions:

> **Some compilers** (most notably MSVC 6
>   and 7) **will let you omit** the `&`, even
>   though it is **non-standard** and
>   confusing. More standard-compliant
>   compilers (e.g., GNU G++ and MSVC 8
>   (a.k.a. VS 2005)) **require it**, so you
>   should definitely put it in. To invoke
>   the member function pointer, you need
>   to provide an instance of SomeClass,
>   and you must use the special operator
>   `->*`. This operator has a low precedence, so you need to put it in
>   parentheses. *[Emphasis added]*

Answer (score 2):

The C++ standard, in its section on Unary operators, states that a pointer-to-member requires explicit use of &.